# Excel search range and return corresponding column number

Tags: excel

I am trying to make my excel document search a range and return the table value of every incidence. In [the picture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvy7x.png), I am trying to enter a formula in the leftmost (green) cell that will search the table (bold outline) for all instances of "Piercing", then return the position of each instance (The corresponding number in the blue row) as a list. What I have in the green cell is what I'd like it to look like. If necessary, I'm ok with it not showing duplicate entries and instead just showing where one of the instances is.

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: Version 2202, build 16.0.14931.20652 if that's important

Comment: Lets try my answer.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work for me, I have the document linked here if you're able to take a look at it. In your example you took out the columns that have the numbers, making the table a bit simpler, however with my use case that is not an option for me without reworking large parts of the sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n15zw2X14jkFBjckfLywY1U_NTDmDHm7/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106348135663519332008&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: You need small correction try `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(G2:Y2,MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(F3:F6),,0),--((G3:Y6="Piercing")))))`  you mistake was in (G2:Y6="Piercing"). This part will start from G3.

Comment: This solution worked great! I would love to extend the table being searched out to the right, to column CG, however when I replace the ranges in your answer to grab the whole table it continues to only get data for the table up to column Y. Here is what I had in that cell: 
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(G2:CG2,MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(F3:F6),,0),--((G3:CG6="Piercing")))))

Comment: Because you do not have word `Piercing` to other columns. Put Piercing to AE4, AM3, CG5 as test purpose then see what result do you get. Also if the answer help then please tick mark the answer to treat as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(C1:L1,MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(C2:C4),,0),--((C2:L4="Piercing")))))
```

And if you have `BYCOL()` function then could try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(C1:L1,BYCOL(C2:L20000,LAMBDA(x,MAX(--(x="Piercing"))))))
```

[image]